# Nativescript concatenate text use Label

Tags: javascript, android, mobile, nativescript

I want to combine string in Label. The result i want is : USD 3000, price number 3000 from database. So i use code :

```
<Label row="2" col="1" text="USD {{ price }}" />
```

but not work and show like this :

```
USD {{ price }}
```

Can i directlly concatenate string in text label ? or any clue about this.
Thanks anyway

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think it should be like this:

```
<Label text="{{ 'USD' + price }}" />
```

Answer (score 4):

Nativescript Angular the format is as follows:

```
 <Label [text]="'Amount: ' + item.Gross"></Label>
```

OR use a pipe to denote the currency:

```
<Label [text]="item.Gross | currency:'USD':true" ></Label>
```